# How to verify a certificate has a specific CA in its certificate chain when using WCF

Tags: wcf, security, x509certificate

I have a requirement to ensure that the x509 certificate that the client presents during a WCF session has a specific Certificate Authority in its chain.

I know I can check certificate chain programmatically using the ChainElements[index].

But I am unsure how to do this while still integrating with WCF using the configuration files.

Currently the WCF is setup in a configuration file, see below:

```
<services>
  <service name="SampleService" behaviorConfiguration="wsHttpBehavior">
    <endpoint name="SampleEndPoint"
              address="http://localhost:70000/SampleService.svc"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="SampleApp.ISampleService">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding">
      <reliableSession enabled="true" ordered="true" />
      <security>
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security> 
    </binding>
  </wsHittpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    <serviceCredentials>
      <serviceCertificate findValue="aa aa aa" 
                          storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
                          storeName="My" 
                          x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber" />
    </serviceCredentials>
  <serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Is there anything that I can do in the configuration file to tell it to make sure the the client certificate that was supplied contains a specific Certificate Authority.  Or do I have to tie into the WCF Channel to accomplish this?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished through WCF's Extensibility ([Introduction to Extensbility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789051.aspx)).

For a specific example ([How to: Createa  Service that Employs a Custom Certificate Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806.aspx))

Using that information and the information that I gathered from [this StackoverFlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147889/c-sharp-verify-certificate-in-crl-list) I created a service that checked the validity of the certificate as well as verifying that it came from a specific Certificate Authority.

Code:

```
public class CustomX509CertificateValidator : X509CertificateValidator
  {
    public override void Validate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
      var ch = new X509Chain();

      //RevocationMode Enumeration
      //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509revocationmode.aspx
      ch.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;

      //RevocationFlag Enumeration
      //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509revocationflag.aspx
      ch.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;

      //The time span that elapsed during online revocation verification or downloading the 
      //certificate revocation list (CRL)
      ch.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(1000);

      //VerificationFlags Enumeration
      //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509verificationflags.aspx 
      ch.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;

      //The time that the certificate was verified expressed in local time
      ch.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime = DateTime.Now;

      ch.Build(certificate);

      //Check to see if the CA is a specific one
      if (ch.ChainElements[ch.ChainElements.Count - 1].Certificate.IssuerName.Name != "CN=Something, OU=PKI...,")
      {
        throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("Certificate was not issued by a trusted issuer");
      }

      foreach (X509ChainStatus s in ch.ChainStatus)
      {
        string str = s.Status.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("str: " + str);
      }

      //Check to see if the current certificate is revoced in the current system (does this not happen in the above?
      X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Disallowed, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
      store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
      bool isRevoked = store.Certificates.Contains(certificate);
      store.Close();

      if (isRevoked)
      {
        throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("Certificate is revoked");
      }

      if (certificate.Verify() == false)
      {
        throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("Certificate cannot be verified");
      }
    }
  }
```

web.config

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="secureHttpBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate  findValue="00 b7 70" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber"/>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom"               
                          customCertificateValidatorType="WcfWebServer.CustomX509CertificateValidator, WcfWebServer"/>
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```